# Codeigniter Docker mysql connection refused eror

Tags: mysql, docker, codeigniter, docker-compose

I have a codeigniter web app that i am running with docker, the issue that i am facing is that docker container cannot connect to mysql server that is running on my host computer..

It seems that docker container can reach the mysql server but connection is refused

Please help me..

I have struggled with this issue for days

Note: the same app, with same docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile can run on windows but not linux (Linux Mint)

**Here is my docker-compose.yml**

```
`version: "3.3"
 services:
  my_app:
  container_name: my_app
  image: aspendigital/codeigniter:latest
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www/html
   restart: always
  ports:
  - "8008:80"
  extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway`
```

**Here is my Docker file**

```
`FROM php:5.6-apache

 RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

 RUN a2enmod rewrite

 #Install Composer
 RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
 RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=. --filename=composer
 RUN mv composer /usr/local/bin/

 COPY . /var/www/html/

 EXPOSE 8008`
```

**Here is my database config file**

```
` $active_group = 'default';
  $active_record = TRUE;


  $db['default']['hostname'] = 'host.docker.internal';
  $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
  $db['default']['password'] = 'app_password';
  $db['default']['database'] = 'app_database_name';
  $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
  $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
  $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
  $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
  $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
  $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
  $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
  $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($db['default']);
  echo '</pre>';

  echo 'Connecting to database: '.$db['default']['database'];

  $mysqli=new mysqli (
  $db['default']['hostname'],
  $db['default']['username'],
  $db['default']['password'],
  $db['default']['database'] );

  if( !$mysqli->connect_error)
  {
    echo '<br /> Connected OK:' ;
    die( 'file: ' .__FILE__ . ' Line: ' .__LINE__);

  } else {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($mysqli->connect_error);
  echo '</pre>';
  }`
```

Comment: where is your mysql server?

Comment: @Ramil Huseynov its on my host computer...installed locally

Comment: Then change $db['default']['hostname'] = 'host.docker.internal'; to your local your mysql ip address

Comment: @Ramil Huseynov i have changes it to 127.0.0.1 but still the problems exits